# merging two tables, while applying aggregates on the duplicates (max,min and sum)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table (let's call it log) with a few millions of records. Among the fields I have Id, Count, FirstHit, LastHit.

- Id - The record id
- Count - number of times this Id has been reported
- FirstHit -  earliest timestamp with which this Id was reported
- LastHit - latest timestamp with which this Id was reported

This table only has one record for any given Id

Everyday I get into another table (let's call it feed) with around half a million records with these fields among many others:

- Id
- Timestamp - Entry date and time.

This table can have many records for the same id

What I want to do is to update log in the following way.
Count - log count value, plus the count() of records for that id found in feed
FirstHit - the earliest of the current value in log or the minimum value in feed for that id
LastHit - the latest of the current value in log or the maximum value in feed for that id.

It should be noticed that many of the ids in feed are already in log.

The simple thing that worked is to create a temporary table and insert into it the union of both as in

```
Select Id, Min(Timestamp) As FirstHit, MAX(Timestamp) as LastHit, Count(*) as Count FROM feed GROUP BY Id
UNION ALL
Select Id, FirstHit,LastHit,Count FROM log;
```

From that temporary table I do a select that aggregates Min(firsthit), max(lasthit) and sum(Count)

```
Select Id, Min(FirstHit),Max(LastHit),Sum(Count) FROM @temp GROUP BY Id;
```

and that gives me the end result. I could then delete everything from log and replace it with everything with temp, or craft an update for the common records and insert the new ones. However, I think both are highly inefficient.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this. Perhaps doing the update in place in the log table?

Comment: + 1 for good question with good presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword here is `EVERYDAY`. You should have a (batch) job which run the process at the end of each day. The idea is process only the record from **yesterday**, this is ways better than process the whole `Feed` table.

### Updated information:

Feed table contains only the hits from last run date. This is much easier with MERGE to update `Log` table:

Notice: We can say `FirstHit` will never be updated. Only `LastHit` and `Count`. Improved from @dened answer.

```
MERGE INTO log l
USING (SELECT Id, MIN(Timestamp) AS FirstHit, MAX(Timestamp) AS LastHit, Count(*) as TodayHit FROM feed GROUP BY Id) f
    ON l.Id = f.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        LastHit = f.LastHit,
        Count = l.Count + f.TodayHit
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Id, FirstHit, LastHit, Count)
    VALUES (f.Id, f.FirstHit, f.LastHit, f.TodayHit);
```

Comment: This is pretty helpful. I didn't know about the merge keyword.
IT is indeed run as a batch and feed only has data from the previous day (or at least since the last merge). After merging everything in feed is deleted.

Comment: Then please see the updated answer. Use the merge statement in the batch job for every run :)

Answer (score 2):

If your SQL Server version is 2008 or later then you can try this:

```
MERGE INTO log l
USING (SELECT Id, MIN(Timestamp) AS FirstHit, MAX(Timestamp) AS LastHit, Count(*) as Count FROM feed GROUP BY Id) f
    ON l.Id = f.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        FirstHit = CASE WHEN l.FirstHit < f.FirstHit THEN l.FirstHit ELSE f.FirstHit END,
        LastHit = CASE WHEN l.LastHit > f.LastHit THEN l.LastHit ELSE f.LastHit END,
        Count = l.Count + f.Count
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Id, FirstHit, LastHit, Count)
    VALUES (f.Id, f.FirstHit, f.LastHit, f.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but I think this should work, not sure how it will perform, though:

```
select
  ifnull(log.Id,feedsum.Id) as Id
, case when log.FirstHit is null then feedsum.FirstHit
       when feedsum.FirstHit is null then log.FirstHit
       when log.FirstHit<feedsum.FirstHit then log.FirstHit
       else feedsum.FirstHit as FirstHit
, case when log.LastHit is null then feedsum.LastHit
       when feedsum.LastHit is null then log.LastHit
       when log.LastHit>feedsum.LastHit then log.LastHit
       else feedsum.LastHit as LastHit       
from
  log
  full outer join (
      Select Id, Min(Timestamp) As FirstHit, MAX(Timestamp) as LastHit, Count(*) as Count FROM feed GROUP BY Id
    ) feedsum using (Id)
```